# Match pattern multiple lines Integromat

Tags: regex, make.com

I want to match specific patterns in multiple lines with the match pattern in Integromat. The language is ECMAScript (JavaScript) FLAVOR.

`Salutation: Mr. x Mx. Mrs.`

or it could look like this:

`Salutation: Mr. Mx. x Mrs.`

I want to get the String after `x\s`, to extract either `Mr.` `Mx.` or `Mrs.`.

Currently, I am at this point, but it only matches if the x is before `Mr.`

`Salutation:\s(x\s(.*?)[\s])`

How do I need to change it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the expected outcome for `Salutation: Mr. x Mx. Mrs.` `Mx. Mrs.` or `Mx.`?

Comment: Does this suit your needs? `\ x (.*)` https://regex101.com/r/A8Pohs/1

Comment: Depending on the answer to my previous comment, it's either that or ` x (\S+)` (maybe `Salutation:.* x (\S+)` to be more specific in what is matched) https://regex101.com/r/9HuYPr/1

Answer (score 0):

You might use a capture group with an alternation to match either a single occurrence of Mr. Mrs. or Mx.

```
\bSalutation:.*?\sx\s(M(?:rs?|x)\.)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bSalutation:` Match literally
- `.*?\sx\s` Match any char as least as possible till the first occurrence of x between whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1** (in the example referred to as `m[1]`)

  - `M(?:rs?|x)\.` Match `M` followed by either r with optional s or x and then a dot
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eEfTSb/1)

```js
const regex = /\bSalutation:.*?\sx\s(M(?:rs?|x)\.)/;
[
  "Salutation: Mr. x Mx. Mrs.",
  "Salutation: Mr. Mx. x Mrs.",
  "Salutation: Mr. Mx. x Mr.",
].forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log(m[1]);
  }
});
```

---

If you want to match all of the occurrences after the x, and a lookbehind is supported in the Javascript version:

```
(?<=\bSalutation:.*\sx\s.*)\bM(?:rs?|x)\.
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KPbZA3/1)